# Mysql left join with having sum() not return all item

Tags: mysql, having

This request return items from tcredit higher than the sum of them in the tcredit_order items.
But I doesn't return the items that are not in the tcredit_order.
I tested other ways like subqueries but it doesn't work and this seems more simple.

```
SELECT * FROM tcredit
LEFT JOIN tcredit_order ON tcredit.id_credit=tcredit_order.id_credit
GROUP BY tcredit.id_credit
HAVING tcredit.credit > SUM(tcredit_order.credit)
ORDER BY tcredit.date_limit ASC
```

Comment: please share some data and table structure along with the expected result.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want, but anyway your query seems to be wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a common trap: as soon as you add a `WHERE`- about a `LEFT JOIN`ed table, you logically and implicitely make it an inner join as long as you do not add a hint about NULL.

```
SELECT * FROM tcredit
LEFT JOIN tcredit_order ON tcredit.id_credit=tcredit_order.id_credit
GROUP BY tcredit.id_credit
HAVING (tcredit.credit > SUM(tcredit_order.credit) or (SUM(tcredit_order) is null))  
ORDER BY tcredit.date_limit ASC
```

That should fix the problem. Remember: `1 > 0` is true, but `1 > NULL` is NULL and not true.

Following the Comment, `coalesce` is a bit cooler (I usually use it for longer chains only).

```
HAVING (tcredit.credit > COALESCE(SUM(tcredit_order.credit),0))
```

Or if you're afraid your coworkers might not know it simply `IFNULL`

```
HAVING (tcredit.credit > IFNULL(SUM(tcredit_order.credit),0))
```

Comment: I guess no need for additional or expression `tcredit.credit > COALESCE(SUM(tcredit_order.credit),0)` this will do the job for null

Comment: Your first fix didn't work, but the last one is OK with the IFNULL.
Yes, I have a WHERE clause in my original query, so you meen that it is the same as INNER JOIN ?
Thanks !

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't have the same result with INNER and LEFT, the LEFT one is OK.

Comment: @polo7: `LEFT JOIN` is meant to give `NULL` results when no entry in the second table is found, and normal `where` clauses filter NULL out (`select * from a left join b on b.a_id = a.id where b.size = 12` is identical to inner join. But if you take care about `b.size is null`, left join does its job. Simply ask yourself about "what if b is missing?").

Comment: @flaschenpost: Yes, thanks, in my case LEFT JOIN is required, because I have credits in credit table not yet spend in credit_order table.

Answer (score -1):

> This request return items from tcredit higher than the sum of them in
>   the tcredit_order items.

There are 2 possibilities one get everything from the table `tcredit` where the credit is greater than sum of credit on the other table and the query should be as

```
select 
tc.* from tcredit tc
left join tcredit_order tco on tco.id_credit = tc.id_credit
group by tc.id_credit 
having  tc.credit > coalesce(sum(tco.credit),0)
```

2nd only data which are present in the first and the second table and in this case

```
select tc.* from tcredit tc
inner join
(
  select 
  id_credit,
  coalesce(sum(credit),0) as tot
  from tcredit_order
  group by id_credit
)tco
on tco.id_credit = tc.id_credit
where tc.credit > tco.tot
```

Comment: And the second one give the same as the first if we change having like:
`having  tc.credit > sum(tco.credit)`

Comment: well the 2nd one is just in case you need to find the records which are present in both the tables and credit of first table is > sum from the 2nd table. I guess in your case LEFT join is enough since it will get all the records irrespective of if its there in the 2nd table or not.